# Bootstrap Carousel auto cycle not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap version 3.1.1

I have hidden the carousel with jquery hide(), when the user clicks a link on the page the carousel appears but the auto cycle doesn't work. It only works if I scroll on the page. I have added the following to script but it doesn't fix the problem.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 3000, cycle: true });
$('.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 3000 }); 
$('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
```

It should help you